# NPM warning TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint even with ESLint installed

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, eslint

I have `ESLint` and not `TSLint` as you can see in my `package.json` here:

```json
{
  "name": "_gui",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "GUI",
  "main": "index.js",
  "browser": {
    "fs": false
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "serve": "webpack serve"
  },
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.1",
    "interactjs": "^1.10.17",
    "mitt": "^3.0.0",
    "roslib": "^1.3.0",
    "three": "^0.145.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.41",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@jridgewell/sourcemap-codec": "^1.4.14",
    "@volar-plugins/vetur": "^0.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint": "^8.29.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.8.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "vue-loader": "^17.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.13",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  }
}
```

Even though I'm getting the following warning! can you please tell me what can I do? thanks in advance.

`npm WARN deprecated tslint@6.1.3: TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint. Please see https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534 for more information.`

Comment: Check your package-lock.json. You should find the package which uses tslint in there. Maybe you can update or even replace it.

Comment: @sandrooco thanks for your kind suggestion, the cause was `"@volar-plugins/vetur"` which depends on `vls` which in turn depends on `tslint`.

Comment: You're not using Vite (instead of Webpack)?

Comment: @kissu as you can see in the `package.json` I use `webpack v5`

Comment: Yeah, I see. My question is more of: "why don't you use Vite?" It's amazing and super fast. Is there a specific reason regarding the usage of Webpack (that Vite could not achieve)? Vue3 comes with Vite by default.

Comment: @kissu I should give it a try, there is no reason for favoring `Webpack` over `Vite`, thanks for your kind suggestion.

Comment: Do you have tslint in your volar.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure [what this](https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar-plugins#readme) is about but having [Volar as an extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vue.volar) for VScode (or else) is totally fine IMO.